# Custom TextBox user control implementing a converter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to build a custom user control, specifically a custom `TextBox` that converts the text entered by the user to uppercase as it is typed and displays it in the control. However, I cannot get this to work. Here is my code:

**CustomTextBox UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SOFWpf.CustomTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SOFWpf.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:CaseConverter x:Key="CaseConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource CaseConverter}}"/>
```

**UserControl's Code-Behind:**

```
  public string Text
  {
     get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
     set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomTextBox Text="a b c"/>
```

**Converter:**

```
   public class CaseConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
         string text = value as string;

         return text?.ToUpper();
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
         string text = value as string;

         return text?.ToLower();
      }
   }
```

What do I need to change to make this custom `TextBox` work as intended?

Comment: Do you want just the displayed text to be uppercase or do you want the actual data behind the textblock to also be uppercase?

Comment: No just to display it!

Comment: Actually there is some problem now, nothing is even displayed!

Comment: You would at least have to bind the TextBox's Text property to that of the UserControl, like `<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, ...}" />`

Comment: If you just want to display the written text in uppercase you do not need a custom control. Just a converter like 
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyPath, Converter={StaticResource CaseConverter}}"/>
You do not need to implement the ConvertBack Method in the converter  as well.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I know. This is just a simple Implementation. It is more complex in real life.

Comment: @Vahid Path=. binds to DataContext, you have to bind to Text property. See clemens comment.

Comment: @Clemens, @ WPFUser The text is displayed now. The ABC , but when I type new text it is in lowercase. The Converter does not get called anymore.

Comment: @Vahid set Mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger as  PropertyChanged

Comment: @WPFUser It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add binding Path=Text:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CaseConverter}}"/>
```

And in the user control constructor set DataContext to this:

```
public CustomTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```